# jQuery - “Uncaught TypeError: content.fadeTo is not a function”

Tags: jquery

My jQuery  code is return an error 'content.fadeTo is not a function'.

Here is my code

```
$.fn.infiniteScroll = function (options) {

        var observer, filesControl = 0, settings;
        settings = $.extend({
            files: [],
            preloaderColor: "#000",
            fadeDuration: 300,
            beforeLoadNewContent: function () { },
            processData: function(data){               
                var content ='<div style="opacity:0;">'+(data)+'/div>';
                $('.' + settings.markSelector).before(content);
                content.fadeTo(settings.fadeDuration, 1);
            },
            afterLoadNewContent: function () { },
            onEnd: function () { }
        }, options);
        settings.markSelector;
```

Comment: `content` is a string, and strings have no such function...

Comment: @CertainPerformance How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

content is just a string. Make it a jQuery object.

`$(content).fadeTo(settings.fadeDuration, 1);` should fix the issue.

or try this

```
var content =$('<div style="opacity:0;">'+(data)+'/div>');
                $('.' + settings.markSelector).before(content);
                content.fadeTo(settings.fadeDuration, 1);
```